# select_related returns value None when querying

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get the `name` field of my Model `Category` but it returns None. I can confirm that there is a value by running `print(post.categories.values())` .
which returns

> QuerySet [{'id': 3, 'name': 'Tasks'}]>

Model:

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.SlugField(max_length = 250, null = True, blank = True)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='posts')

class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

View:

```
def blog_index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_on')
    context = {
        "posts": posts,
    }
    return render(request, "blog_index.html", context)


def blog_category(request, category):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(
        categories__name__contains=category
    ).order_by(
        '-created_on'
    )
    if not posts:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    context = {
        "category": category,
        "posts": posts
    }
    return render(request, "blog_category.html", context)

def blog_detail(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.select_related().get(pk=pk)
    print(post.categories.name) # Returns None!!
    form = CommentForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = Comment(
                author=form.cleaned_data["author"],
                body=form.cleaned_data["body"],
                post=post
            )
            comment.save()

    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
    context = {
        "post": post,
        "comments": comments,
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "blog_detail.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) is only a performance booster, that follows foreign-key relationships. In you case you have no [models.Foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) in Post object so this is not doing any optimizations at all.

You are having [`models.ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) between post and category, that means that you can have more than one category for post. To get names of categories you should iterate through post.categories list

```
print([category.name for category in post.categories.all()])
```

Also if you are wondering there is an optimization for this type of relationship with [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Comment: This causes exception `'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable`

Also I do believe I have a foreign-key relationship. I have some other functions that I didn't post as I thought they wouldn't be relevant. I've linked these to my admin page, so I can create posts in there. I've updated the original question with the functions.

Comment: Your update outputs almost what I want. The outputs is `['MyValue']` but is it possible to get it without the brackets so it's just the pure value?

Comment: forgot .all() in example, you clearly have many to many relationship between categories and posts ->
categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='posts'),

Comment: if you are not going to have more than one category for post you should change relationship type, in this case you can get first element post.categories.all()[0].name but that would show only one tag ( as your database design currently points out there could be multiple tags that is why output is an array)

Comment: There is indeed multiple values. I just want to grab the value of the `name` column in my `Category` model. That's really it.